# .get_object() showing dataset rather than field data from model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm building a website that displays recipes from cookbooks on a page.

Here is what I have so far

models.py

```
class cookbook(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)

class ingredient (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)


class recipesteps(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(ingredient,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    instructions = models.TextField()
    time =  models.IntegerField(default=0)

class recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    cookbook = models.ForeignKey(cookbook,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient_used = models.ManyToManyField(ingredient)
    recipe_steps = models.ForeignKey(recipesteps,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
           return 'name={}   cookbook={} `'.format(self.name,self.cookbook)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class RecipeDetailView(DetailView):
 model = recipe
     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(RecipeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['instructions'] = recipesteps.objects.filter(recipe=self.get_object())
return context
```

template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>{{ object.cookbook }}</h2>
<h2> Recipe Name = {{ object.name }} </h2>
<h2> Steps To Make:</h2>
 {{ instructions }} 
</body>
</html>
```

The output of the {{ instructions }} variable in the template is :

```
<QuerySet [<recipesteps: name=Tomato cookbook=Cooking with tomato >, <recipesteps: name=Lettuce cookbook= Cooking with lettuce >]>
```

Is there a way I can show just the name of the ingredient at one point in the template and also show the cookbook at another point without the  ?

Comment: What is `totalcontent`, you are doing `totalcontent.objects.filter` but didnt show us that model?

Comment: sorry this should be recipesteps I was copying from another question

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the instructions objects

```
{% for instruction in instructions %}
   {{instruction.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add the extra context, you could do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>{{ object.cookbook }}</h2>
<h2> Recipe Name = {{ object.name }} </h2>
<h2> Steps To Make:</h2>
 {% for instruction in object.instructions.all %}
    {{instruction.name}}
 {% endfor %} 
</body>
</html>
```

Your object already has access to instructions.